# Fit a harmonic oscilator via step response

Tags: step-response, differential-equation

Suppose we are studying a dynamic system believed to be well modeled via

$$
x'' + \frac bm x' + \frac cm x = \frac Fm$$
$x''$ - acceleration
$b$ - damping factor
$c$ - spring rate
$F$ - external force.

I remember studying - but can't find my notes - a formula for estimating $b/m$ and $c/m$ from eyeballing a step response. The damping coefficient was determined mostly by the number of oscillations while the spring constant was associated with some times. What are those formulas?

Comment: If you're sure the system is highly resonant, pick out the resonant frequency by the zero crossings, and pick out the decay of the envelope by the magnitudes halfway between the zero crossings.  If you're _not_ sure the system is highly resonant, then Google "ARMA", and use that with the step response as the input for the "MA" part.

Comment: I was curious and I googled "ARMA", this is what it gave me https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arma.

Comment: (Smacks forehead) -- [Autoregressive Moving Average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive%E2%80%93moving-average_model).  It may not be the _best_ tool in system identification (I honestly don't know) but it's most people's _first_ and often last tool.